# I want to create a new event for ChildWindow OnWidthChanged how do i do it in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, events

I want to create a new event for Silverlight ChildWindow where when the width changes the event must be raised how do i do it in C#/Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the existing SizeChanged event Compare NewSize and PreviousSize in SizeChangedEventArgs to check if width has changed.